# Finding effective rate

Tags: finance

Suppose a mortgage has an interest rate of 6.5% per annum with
monthly compounding. Find the per annum interest rate with quarterly
compounding that would lead to the same effective annual rate.

I solved this one by:

$$r_eff = (1+\frac{0.065}{12}^{12})-1 =0.067%$$
   $$(1+\frac{r}{4})^4-1=0.067$$
    $$=(1+\frac{r}{4})= (1+0.067)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Solving for r, I get 6.52%

Now how would I find the rate with continuous compounding
that would lead to the same effective annual rate?
 I understand that the formula is $$A=Pe^{rt}$$ How would I set up the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A/P = e^{rt}$

You have already found the effective annual interest rate $=0.067$

Taking that to be correct, $e^r = 1+0.067$

Solve for $r$